# Changing the database before throwing an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a microservice architecture in which every microservice implements the usual Controller->Service->Repository flow.

I'm using exceptions to handle errors and control the flow, i.e. instead of using DTO fields to return status fields, all DTOs are used to return "positive" scenario results, while "negative" scenarios throw exceptions in the Service layer. This is working like a charm and allows me to offload a lot of checks from controllers into ControllerAdvice classes which have custom error handling, but there is a strange situation that I've run into.

Sometimes a negative scenario requires a database change before an exception is thrown, for example an error while operating on a hypothetical User table requires the User entity to be deleted, after the User is deleted the exception is thrown to trigger an Error message to be sent via REST.

```
public UserDto changeUserAndReturnTheObject(String userId) {
       UserDto user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(
                      () -> new MyCustomException("There is no user under that userId: " + userId));
       if(!user.isValid()) {
           userRepository.remove(user);
           throw new MyCustomException("The user data is invalid, it will be removed!");   
       }
       //change the User in some way
       return user;
}
```

My question is this, since RuntimeExceptions trigger rollbacks, how can I differentiate between DB operations that need to be rolled back, and those that are "corrective" operations that need to be executed in the case of an error? I could have MyCustomException be an UncheckedException, but what if I had an operation before the if that throws the exception that writes something to DB and that now needs to be rolled back? I have some ideas of my own, but they seem to be a bit hacky and unclean. For example, I could create Exception type that accepts a callback that can execute the DB change after an exception is thrown and use it as such:

```
if(!user.isValid()) {
   throw new RollbackException("The user data is invalid, it will be removed!", () -> userRepository.remove(user));   
}

@ExceptionHandler(RollbackException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleRollbackException(RollbackException ex) {    
        log.error("An exception has occurred", ex);
        ex.executeCallback();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("I probably need a custom class for this", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Again, this seems like working around the framework instead of using its features. Is there a tried and true way for handling these situations?

Comment: There are indeed many ways to achieve this, but you could create a method in another service class annotated with @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: That seems much better than my original idea! Would creating a new method annotated with REQUIRES_NEW in the same service work, or does the method need to be in a new service class?

Comment: No because @Transactional are handled with Spring AOP by proxying your beans,  you need to call a method on the reference of the bean proxy to trigger AOP interceptor (and start your transaction), if you call it from the same class, you're going to call your method on "this", which is not a reference to the bean proxy, and will not trigger any AOP aspect. It's a common problem with runtime AOP. The documentation explain it well (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s06.html)